# Help with my problems creating USB from Windows

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows

I have a computer with Windows 7. I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 or 12.04 onto my usb stick, so I can boot from it and use Ubuntu. I have so far downloaded the desktop version download on the website and the usb creator recommended. I have followed the instructions and when I boot from the usb, I just get a black screen and nothing ever happens. I tried both the 64 and 32 bit version of 13.10 with the same results. can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: there are many questions regarding this issue. see this for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

first of all, what usb creator are you using? I'd recommend unetbootin if only because I've used it many times. Second, check the md5sum of your .iso file -- follow these instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

That will tell you if the file was corrupted during the download. Finally, if none of this works, unetbootin has a useful no-mess direct download, format and install option, edit, which is worth trying, as is trying a different usb stick, a different distro etc. till something works (then work from there).

Comment: he said that he used the "recommended usb creator"; he means that he used unetbootin